# How to add wildcard certificate fastapi & uvicorn

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, fastapi, uvicorn

My project is developed using Python `fastapi` and front end developed in angular 16, the front end is running by `apache` server with `ssl/ https` using port 443, and another spring boot service using same `ssl` certificate and using the port 8443, my server in Ubuntu and `ssl` using wildcard certificate , i need to run fast API with same server using the same wildcard certificate with different port

This is what i tried.

from unicorn.

```
main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8444 --ssl-keyfile /home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/wildcard_project_com_private_key.key --ssl-certfile /home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/certificate.pem --ssl-ca-certs /home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/chain.pem
```

And from `fastapi` code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    certfile = "/home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/certificate.pem"
    keyfile = "/home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/wildcard_project_com_private_key.key"
    cafile = "/home/ubuntu/project/ssl_wildcard/chain.pem"
    ssl_context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLS)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)
    ssl_context.verify_mode = CERT_REQUIRED
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8442, ssl_version=ssl_context)
```

and i got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 48, in <module>
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(certfile=certfile, keyfile=keyfile)
   ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4067)
```